# I hard reset my computer while it was starting up, now Ubuntu is acting up

Tags: boot

Fortunately, it still starts up, but it shows a login screen despite automatic login being on. I can open up terminal and files seconds after logging it, but if I take too long or close them, they con no longer be opened ever. I've looked up guides to repair ubuntu, but nothing has worked. I really don't want to have to reinstall it.

Comment: Hi Mitchell, welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please edit your question to include the version of Ubuntu you are running, and if possible what you have tried so far to repair it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any custom config files, you can try deleting cache, and the config directories in your home directory.

```
rm -r ~/.cache ~/.config ~/.local
```

Then restart the computer.

I recommend that you back up them just in case. Ubuntu will regenerate these the next time you restart.

Comment: It's maybe worth a try but I'd strongly recommend to make backups of `~/.config` and `~/.local` (or simply rename them first) because they contain precious information for all kinds of applications. For example, the preferences of `GEdit` are stored below `~/.config`and all these settings were gone if that directory is deleted.